# Is there the way to get that text is too big to be displayed on snackbar

Tags: android

I have fixed length of Material Snackbar: 3 lines. Text can have any length. Is there the way to get that text is too big to be displayed on snackbar? I want to use this way to display text on modal window if text is too big.